# OpenCV Android- Unsatisfied Link Error

Tags: java, android, opencv, mobile

So I have an Android App that uses OpenCV. I keep trying to run but I get Unsatisfied Link Errors.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.hairsimulator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ImageView view;
private static Activity myActivity;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myActivity = this;
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); 
    while (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.e("suck","suck");
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); 
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    view = (CustView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    AssetManager manager = getAssets();
    Bitmap bitmap;
    // read a Bitmap from Assets
    InputStream open = null;
    try {
      open = manager.open("back.png");
      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(open);
      view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      ((CustView) view).setBits(bitmap);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 
    finally {
        if (open != null) {
          try {
            open.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
    }
}

public static Activity getActivity() {
    return myActivity;
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void startUp(View v) {
    view.setOnTouchListener(new JobListener(true)); 
}
}
```

If I comment out the code that logs "suck,suck", then I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError. I have the OpenCV library and everything else installed. I just don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me please.

Comment: What are you doing? Have you tried this tutorial http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html yet?

Answer (score 0):

You may start with analyzing your project dependency. For doing that you can use dependency walker. So you can see what going wrong. Another important thing is that you must ensure that you use right architecture. If you use x64 and call x32 or vice versa, unsatisfied link error is unavoidable. I think your problem is not programmatic, there is just little bit configuration error.

Comment: I tried but the tutorial just sucks. It doesn't have enough information.

Comment: Ensure your arhitecture platform as a first step. Then you can use dependency walker application for finding linkage.